# CSS/HTML : Putting up a text label on my image

Tags: html, image, css

I want to put a small text label on the image. Can someone help me out with that ?

Putting the image in the div's background and writing on it is an option but as I am working on a dynamic project, I need to keep the css static

Here is what I have tried :

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image">
  <p class="text">Category</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image{
 height:40%;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:2px;
 background-image:url(Lighthouse.jpg);
 background-size:100% auto;
 }
```

Using this I have created something like this : [image: Image with the label]

Now, as I am going to use Django, I don't want the image to be in css. I want to place it in my html file.

Comment: Anything in CSS can be changed dynamically.  But regardless, you need to give us more to go on than this.  Like, what have you tried, where are you stuck and maybe post your code for us to look at

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you really need it in the HTML you can do something like this:

### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6vVNs/)

### HTML:

```
<div class="imgHolder">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    <span>Here's the overlay text</span>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.imgHolder {
    position: relative;
}
.imgHolder span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

And of course change your `<img src="">` to a variable from python.

Comment: Yup ! Got it :) Thanks Deryck. Done !