# CSS/HTML Putting two rows of a text on my image

Tags: html, css

I want to put two rows of text on my image. Similar question was answered here [CSS/HTML : Putting up a text label on my image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878929/)

```css
.imgHolder {
  position: relative;
}
.imgHolder span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgHolder">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt=""/>
  <span>Here's the overlay text<br>Second row</span>
</div>
```

It works great but I can’t change the formatting of the second row at all (text size). Everything breaks up the text position. :(

I also can’t understand how the `span` tag works in the external CSS.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you put each line of text in its own `p` tag?  You can then format each tag separately.

Comment: @Niksr : Here is what you want : https://jsfiddle.net/d0oe0ywy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/xwfsxkrt/

The HTML:

```
<div class="imgHolder">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  <span class="top">Here's the overlay text</span>
  <span class="bottom">Second row</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.imgHolder {
  position: relative;
}
.imgHolder span.top {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color:green;
}
.imgHolder span.bottom{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 30px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

I added the `background-color` as evidence that you can style each row anyway you want. `span` works the same way in the CSS as anything else, your only problem was differentiating between your two rows, which requires two `span` classes.

Answer (score 0):

1: use 'float:left' for the div. Now the div stretches over the full width of the page meaning that the text will float absolute at the right of the page (because that is the edge of the div). Width float:left the div will be as wide as the contents. Meaning that the edge of the div will be the edge of the image.

2. Place the text in a div ("textholder") for positioning instead of positioning the 'spans' under each other, which is more of a hassle.
3. Make seperate spans and classes/styles for the first and second row of text.

The result:

```css
.imgHolder {
  position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.textholder {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.textholder span.top {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color:green;
}
.textholder span.bottom{
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgHolder">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    <div class="textholder"><span class="top">Here's the overlay text</span><br><span class="bottom">Second row</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really good because I don't need to care about position of every raw depends on font size. Thank you!!

Comment: But I can't now align second row against first row :(